# Inyectar elementos de una posición determinada de un objeto Json en un DIV

Tags: html, json, jsonobject

Lo que quiero es imprimir los elementos de la posición 3 de un objeto json dentro de un DIV  que tiene una clase llamada "test"

Este es mi Objeto:

```
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 

0: {id: "3", titulo: "Rosas vinedos", imagen: "140302231.jpg"} 
1: {id: "4", titulo: "Gran vino tinto", imagen: "140326554.jpg"} 
2: {id: "5", titulo: "uvas frescas", imagen: "140326657.jpg"} 
3: {id: "6", titulo: "Entrada chateou", imagen: "140327792.jpg"} 
4: {id: "7", titulo: "Vinedos", imagen: "140327853.jpg"} 
5: {id: "8", titulo: "uvas vinedos", imagen: "140327295.jpg"} 
6: {id: "9", titulo: "El gran vino blanco", imagen: "140327768.jpg"} 
7: {id: "10", titulo: "Vinedos carro", imagen: "140328796.jpg"} 
8: {id: "11", titulo: "Degustaciones", imagen: "140328169.jpg"} 
9: {id: "0", titulo: "Vista Aerea", imagen: "1561407251_thump.jpg"} 
10: {id: "0", titulo: "Barriles", imagen: "1561407463_thump.jpg"} 
11: {id: "0", titulo: "Botellas", imagen: "1561407568_thump.jpg"} 
12: {id: "0", titulo: "Evento", imagen: "1561407670_thump.jpg"}
```

Comment: Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Y desde donde lo querés imprimir? Backend? Frontend? Alguna librería/framework en particular? Detallá un poco más lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que hacer algo similar a lo siguiente:

```js
let myJsonObject = [
    {id: "3", titulo: "Rosas vinedos", imagen: "140302231.jpg"},
    {id: "4", titulo: "Gran vino tinto", imagen: "140326554.jpg"},
    {id: "5", titulo: "uvas frescas", imagen: "140326657.jpg"},
    {id: "6", titulo: "Entrada chateou", imagen: "140327792.jpg"}
    ]

//Primera opción
$("#jsonContent").html(JSON.stringify(myJsonObject[3]));


//O también
let text = '';
Object.keys(myJsonObject[3]).forEach(key => {
  text += key + " : " + myJsonObject[3][key] + "</br>";
})
$("#jsonContent2").html(text);
```

```css
#jsonContent2{
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="jsonContent"></div>
<div id="jsonContent2"></div>
```

Este ejemplo lo he hecho con JQuery, en caso de necesitar solo JS puedo editarlo. En el primero ejemplo hacemos un JSON.stringify para poder hacer uso del objeto convirtiéndolo a string, en el segundo solo iteramos entre cada llave y mostramos su valor.

Comment: men y si solo necesito imprimir un elemento de determinada posicion como la imagen o el titulo sin recorrerlo, como seria el syntax?

Comment: $("#jsonContent").html(myJsonObject[3].titulo); y listo, es solo agregar un punto y el nombre de la llave, si fuese el caso de que la llave tenga dos palabras se haría así myJsonObject[3]["dos palabras"] y debe arrojar el valor.